# Excel VBA: Force user to save as .xlsm

Tags: vba, excel

I have a series of macros that automates much of a process. I would like to distribute this to my coworkers via Excel Add-In and I have one piece of code I just can't seem to get right.

Here is the "master" code (which works fine):

```
Option Explicit

Sub MIUL_Run_All()

Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As String

'Remember time when macro starts
StartTime = Timer

Call OptimizeCode_Begin

Call Save_As
Call Format_MIUL
Call Custom_Sort_MIUL
Call Insert_Process_List
Call Format_Process_List

Call OptimizeCode_End

'Determine how many seconds code took to run
SecondsElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "ss")

'Notify user in seconds
MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", 
vbInformation

End Sub
```

The code that is giving me trouble is "Save_As". First thing I want the user to do is to save the file as a macro enabled file. Ideally, I want the code to do these things for the user:

1. Force the user to save as .xlsm
2. Provide the current file name in the Save As dialog box so they have a file name to already work with.
3. If the CANCEL button is pressed it must stop the entire macro!

I thought this would be a fairly trivial thing, but so far it has been the toughest part of my code.

Here is what I have tried for the Save_As code:

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show , xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

This code is very simple, but it doesn't address the cancel button.

```
Dim userResponse As Boolean

On Error Resume Next  
userResponse = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show(52) 
On Error GoTo 0 
If userResponse = False Then
Exit Sub 
Else 
End If
```

Again for some reason this doesn't address the cancel button.

I have tried probably a half a dozen different things, most of which are similar to the above codes.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: userResponse = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show(52)  will bring up the dialogbox with 52.xlsx as the file name.  The first argument of the dialogbox is file name.  52 as the second argument will force the XLSM file type.  I ran your code and it worked perfectly.  I'm not sure if you need the error lines.

Comment: @mooseman the problem is that the next code starts to run as it exits that specific Sub and moves onto the next code which is "Call Format_MIUL". How can I make it break from the entire code?

Comment: You mean you call this sub from another and want all code to stop when cancel is chosen?  That will take an overall design.  Maybe set up a global variable and set it if userResponse = False.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
If FileDialog.Show = False Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Which does not account for an error, simply recognizing a state.  You will want the Exit Sub to happen if there's an error only.

---

This error handling could be implemented by replacing :

```
On Error Resume Next  
userResponse = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show(52) 
On Error GoTo 0 
If userResponse = False Then
    Exit Sub 
Else 
End If
```

With:

```
On Error GoTo Cat  
userResponse = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show(52) 

Cat: 
    Exit Sub
```

Comment: I am a little bit confused. Are you saying to implement your first piece of code with the second piece of code in my OP?

Comment: @CC268 Sorry about that; I was saying that (From the posted code) the triggered error on anything happening after the userResponse should trigger Exit Sub.  This would mean you don't need the If-statement after the file dialogue is visible.  As you have written (what I was trying to get to in the first part of my answer) was that the If statement is in sequence with the rest of the code, not happening if an error occurs.

Comment: Only problem is that the cancel button on the dialog box is not an error.  If there is any code between the userResponse line and the Cat: line it will process that code.